# Isotope troubles with layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am working on this site:

http://www.thecarlossanchez.com/Test/thecarlossanchez/Galleries/stilltest.html

When I created the thumbnails everything worked great, but for some reason it added all this extra space if you scrolled to the right. Everything worked the way it should with in the window and it never made me scroll right ever, so I ignored the extra space.

Now I am adding Isotope in order to filter the content, but when a category is selected all the thumbnails drop down and to the right. Something is centering the content to all that extra space. And I am not familiar enough with jquery to figure what where the problem is.

Here is an example of how it should work without isotope:

http://www.thecarlossanchez.com/Galleries/people.html

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking on your site, I noticed you got an enormous `padding` size being set on your `gallery` element.

Currently it's :

```
.gallery{
    width:80%; 
    padding:800px; /* enormous padding */
    position:relative;
}
```

I've changed that to `padding: 0;` and the extra space at the right side is removed.

`.gallery` should look like this now:

```
.gallery{
    width:80%; 
    padding:0; 
    position:relative;
}
```

Also if you want to center your gallery when the page is resized, add `margin: 0 auto` to `.gallery` element.

e.g.

```
.gallery{
    width:80%; 
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto; /* center gallery */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how I overlooked the 800px padding, but with a few more minor adjustments your solution worked great! Thank you!

Comment: @smalltrades Cool! Glad it helped.